# How do I Get this result by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server

- 1: Accounts
- 2: Transaction_Body

And I have 2 dates and I want to get result like in the fourth picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is result that I want from the query

[image]

And this code all I could GET

```
SELECT    Accounts.AccName, 
          SUM(ISNULL(Transaction_Body.Debt, 0)) AS [total debet],
          SUM(ISNULL(Transaction_Body.Credit, 0)) AS [total Credit] 
FROM      Accounts 
LEFT JOIN Transaction_Body 
       ON Accounts.AccID = Transaction_Body.AccID 
GROUP BY  Accounts.AccName
```

Can someone assist me to get the results I want? Thank You

Comment: you can use [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to perform the conditional sum for `before`, `between` and `before+between` respectively. Also please avoid using image and post the sample data etc as formatted text

Comment: Did you try what Squirrel suggested? Happy to fix your code, if you can provide sample data tables (with few rows) in a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I am sorry Fro These images  I will notice this at next time  But can u edit my code to insert case .. Please show me and thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something for you to begin with. You can try this code out and let us know how it goes. FYI: this is not the most efficient code and possibly the most basic and takes 6ms - 20ms to perform on 10-15 rows in sqlfiddle. Note on sqlfiddle this time appears to vary on single aggregate query compared to nested aggregate query. I am not using a sql server at hand to check this any further.
This answer also doesn't contain your exact data since you didn't provide sample table/data query. You can improve this code by appreciating the execution plan and other methods/ways that you can use to replicate the same results in SQL server. I strongly suggest you to provide the table create and insert statements next time when you post a SQL question. At minimum provide that using SQLFiddle, so might get better help from willing community.  a, b, c, d column names in my sample output refers to the column tables of the query.

```
/*variables for date inputs and 6ms-20ms, varies*/

DECLARE @dt1 AS Date='2018-01-01'
DECLARE @dt2 AS Date='2018-02-01'
DECLARE @dt3 AS Date='2018-03-01'


SELECT t.name
            , SUM(DB1) AS DEBTDATEBEFORE
            , SUM(CB1) AS CREDDATEBEFORE
            , SUM(DB2) AS DEBTDATEBETWEEN
            , SUM(CB2) AS CREDDATEBETWEEN
FROM (
SELECT s.tid 
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate < @dt2
             THEN s.moneyD 
               ELSE 0 END AS DB1
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate < @dt2 
             THEN s.moneyC
               ELSE 0 END AS CB1
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt3 
             THEN s.moneyD
               ELSE 0 END AS DB2
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt3 
             THEN s.moneyC
               ELSE 0 END AS CB2
             
FROM s) x
LEFT JOIN t
ON x.tid = t.tid
GROUP BY t.name
;

/*13 ms plan - seems be a steady 13ms most of the time*/

SELECT t.name
            , SUM(DB1) AS DEBTDATEBEFORE
            , SUM(CB1) AS CREDDATEBEFORE
            , SUM(DB2) AS DEBTDATEBETWEEN
            , SUM(CB2) AS CREDDATEBETWEEN
FROM (
SELECT s.tid 
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate < @dt2
             THEN SUM(ISNULL(s.moneyD, 0)) 
               ELSE 0 END AS DB1
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate < @dt2 
             THEN SUM(ISNULL(s.moneyC, 0))
               ELSE 0 END AS CB1
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt3 
             THEN SUM(ISNULL(s.moneyD, 0))
               ELSE 0 END AS DB2
             , CASE WHEN s.sdate BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt3 
             THEN SUM(ISNULL(s.moneyC, 0))
               ELSE 0 END AS CB2
             
FROM s
GROUP BY s.tid, s.sdate) x
LEFT JOIN t
ON x.tid = t.tid
GROUP BY t.name
;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cba135/11)**

Output

```
name    a       b      c    d
Anne    1000    0      3000 0
Doe     600     0      1300 0
John    0       700    0    1500
Mary    0       100    0    300
Neo     300     0      700  0
```

See Execution Plan here:
10ms
[image: Execution Plan 10ms]

13ms
[image: Execution Plan 13ms]

Donate to SQLFiddle if you benefit from it. Not my product.

Comment: WOW .. thank you very much Bro it's worked with me  just i changed name fields and ( left join ) to ( right Join ) thank you very much

Comment: But I don't understand this part here ( X ) >> ( On X.tid = t.tid )  where x come from ?

Comment: Here's some [table alias, nested derived table info](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6038/sql-server-derived-table-example/) from MSSQL. These theoretical techniques do apply commonly across most db systems. Have a read and do some practice. `X` is a `table alias` that refers to the derived table of the join, and it's temporary.